# upload an image from phonegap app to the server (servlet)

Tags: android, servlets, cordova

How can I upload a picture of my Phonegap app to a server using servlet?

My function looks like this:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = true;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://131.246.37.167**/upload**", win, fail, options);
```

My servlet like this:

public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "C:/uploads";

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //process only if its multipart content
    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                     new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                }
            }

           //File uploaded successfully
           request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
        }          

    }else{
        request.setAttribute("message",
                             "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

}

Der web.xml(Tomcat eclipse).

```
.... 

 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>FileUploadHandler</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>FileUploadHandler</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>FileUploadHandler</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>**/upload**</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
....
```

Please does anyone have an idea?

Michael

Comment: Where is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed to add port number of server along with IP address.

```
ft.upload(imageURI, "http://131.246.37.167:8080/**/upload**", win, fail, options);
```